# Disable "Saving Snapshot" in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, snapshot

How can I disable saving snapshot in NetBeans 7.1.2? It is slowing down the system dramatically. Any suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The snapshots are performance snapshots taken when the IDE detects slow behavior. For obvious reasons, slower computers are more likely to trigger the collection (by taking longer than a preset amount of time to complete tasks), which then requires saving the snapshot. The saving process slows the system down even more, occasionally resulting in (for all practical purposes) an inoperable IDE.

Check your `netbeans.conf` configuration file (in the `etc` folder). You'll find a line for `netbeans_default_options`. Make sure `-J-ea` does not appear in the line. This flag enabled Java assertions, which wouldn't be a problem in itself but the slowness detector in NetBeans also uses this flag to significantly shorten the timeout before the self-profiler is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Sam Harnell's answer didn't help me in 2019 and NetBeans 10, because i didn't had the option -J-ea. I found help in the [NetBeans bugtracker](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=186690) .
Adding the below options to `netbeans_default_options` helped me to get rid of the *saving snapshots*:

```
-J-Dorg.netbeans.core.TimeableEventQueue.report=30000 
-J-Dorg.netbeans.core.TimeableEventQueue.quantum=1000 
-J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.slowness.report=10000
```

Comment: On my Netbeans 11, -J-ea was also missing. So your answer saved a lot of unresponsive time!