# Snapshot was saved to... pop-up window in NETBEANS

Tags: html, netbeans, popup, popupwindow, snapshot

When I insert an HTML tag into Netbeans, a snapshot window will pop up. Any suggestion?

[image: Snapshot window]

Comment: Suggestions about what? What is the problem?

Comment: Have you searched for and seen
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667914/disable-saving-snapshot-in-netbeans ?